# is @unlink a bad practice?

Tags: php

I'm usually against using `@` as it can cause lots of headaches. But look at this two examples:

```
a)

if(file_exists('file'))
    unlink('file');
```

.

```
b)

@unlink('file');
```

.

It sounds like `b` is causing less disk lookups, which is good for performance. So my question is: **would option `b` cause me any problem or has any disavantages in relation to `a`?**

Comment: What if there is another reason why the file couldn't be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just go for the first one.

What if the file couldn't be deleted because of another reason than simply the fact that the file doesn't exist?

Comment: but, if I make sure my folder is writable in the beggining of the script, could I gain in performance with the option `b`? For example in a case where I really need to improve performance and I'm sure i configured my environment correctly...

Comment: Wouldn't that also be a call to the filesystem?

Comment: but one time in the beggining against possible several times during script running...